# GitHub repo link not showing in marketplace

Tags: github, visual-studio-extensions, marketplace

I published 2 extensions to the VS marketplace, in the manifest file and on the marketplace I added the source code github link. When I go to the marketplace, there is no link to the repository or showing open issues/pull requests.

Is there anything I forget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the extensions are for vs. It's fairly easy to publish it to marketplace as we all know.
Please remove the github links in manifest file,and check the github url again:

[image]

I think maybe there has something wrong with your link here. I've done several tests and find the `Project Details Section` would disappear only when the github link was not valid for a github repo.(Even the github repo is private, the link to repo will display.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I used 'http' instead of 'https'. Changing this fixed my issue.

Comment: @Epsilekt If this solved your problem, please consider checking it as the "accepted answer" to your question. ;)  Have a good day!